# Did a vegan dog live for 29 years?

Tags: nutrition, dogs, animal-welfare

According to [PETA's *"Meatless Meals for Dogs and Cats"*,](https://www.peta.org/issues/animal-companion-issues/animal-companion-factsheets/meatless-meals-dogs-cats/)

> One remarkable example is that of Bramble, a border collie whose **vegan diet of rice, lentils, and organic vegetables contributed to a nearly record-breaking lifespan of 29 years.**

Did this ever happen? Is there any evidence of this?

Comment: Of interest: https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/oldest-dog

Answer (score 37):

According to a (2021) [interview](https://v-dog.com/blogs/v-dog-blog/bramble-the-collies-secrets-to-living-to-age-25) with Bramble's owner ([cited](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_longest_living_dogs&oldid=1101346918) by Wikipedia), Bramble lived 25 (and 1/4 or so) years (not 29), i.e.  1978-2003. If you click on that link you'll discover that it's a vegan dog food shop hosting the interview. And the owner of Bramble is also vegan. I'm not sure if there's any further verification of the (corrected) claim beyond that.

Comment: If you want to address the "…VX contributed to…"-part: include the average life-span of the breed and [Meet Skippy, a 26-Year-Old Border Collie Who Is the “Oldest Dog in Ireland”](https://mymodernmet.com/skippy-26-year-old-dog/), since dogs are adpated to much less meat compared to wolves anyway, and while Bramble was old, he may only hold a record for 'meatless-fed', but not for 'adequately/optimally fed'… ;) What does eg Guiness say to such recorded dog lifespans? Old-Hemp only reached 8 years?

Comment: @LangLаngС where can I find more information about Old-Hemp?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Star here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Hemp

Comment: @EvanCarroll For comparing & context of 'record dog lifespans', I guess info like https://www.scotsman.com/lifestyle/family-and-parenting/whats-the-oldest-dog-ever-these-are-the-10-amazing-dogs-that-have-lived-record-breaking-lives-up-to-29-years-3323836 should be added here (but maybe of better source quality than _that_ paper I found)?

Comment: @LangLаngС: I'm not sure if going into those kinds of comparisons would constitute "original research" as far this site goes. You can post your own answer... Generally speaking, comparing the 0.01% extremes isn't too useful in science.

Comment: Lots of implicit claims in Q, low response. / Low interest in a _competing answer,_ much more in _a complete answer_. 'Claim false' based on  25 years, not 29? (Or religious beliefs of dog owner?) — 25 _is_ very senior an age for the breed; 25 is pretty old for 'inadequately/cruelly' (choose words wisely) fed 'just vegs',  but you don't tell (not much OR required)—and that leaves your readers wondering: is that bit a lower value 'still a lot', 'thanks to' (or despite), 'compared to what', etc. Adding some of this context would be rather cheap, but gains substantial. My offer, your choice.

Comment: The fact Bramble was owned by someone who makes a living selling the dog's diet should be raising lots of red flags. They have a strong financial incentive to exaggerate the dog's age. Was the claimed age of 25 ever actually verified by anyone?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: FWTW, she says on the wikipedia talk page she only makes $3/month or so from selling those stories/recipes. Also claims to have veterinary records proving the dog's age, but that there was no real interest by Guinness etc. to look at them (probably because they don't plan on adding a veggie dog life record.)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft That is not the only doubt that could be raised. It is also possible that the owners raised many dogs and made a lot of publicity to the outlier.

Comment: I do think the financial incentive to fabricate the story can inform the answer. Regardless of what she makes, she could have intended to make more with the story. It seems like we accept that it was a priority to make something.

Comment: @CJDennis That's not the claim being asked about in the Q.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Where do you see that Anne Heritage makes money off selling vegan dog food?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- No, it's not the claim, but it's implied otherwise it wouldn't be claimed in the first place. You're supposed to think that dogs do better on a vegan diet. Look! My dog lived a really long time on a vegan diet! Therefore all dogs should be fed a vegan diet!